# NextJs Get transaction response from Paypal

Tags: paypal, next.js

I want to write an api endpoint where you can put an order id inside the request and with the paypal api I want to check the status of the payment state.

[Paypal Dev Link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/get-transaction/)

The above link seems to be the solution but they dont have an Next.JS example. I tried to follow along on the node integration, but I cant get it working..

The payment itself im doing with "@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^6.0.2", if this information is useful.

This is my code, but im getting no order its undefined in step 5...

```
const checkoutNodeJssdk = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk');

const clientId = 'clientid';
const clientSecret = 'secret';
const environment = new checkoutNodeJssdk.core.SandboxEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret);
const payPalClient = new checkoutNodeJssdk.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment);


const handler = (req, res) => {

    // 2a. Get the order ID from the request body
  const orderID = '1243324';

  // 3. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
  let request = new checkoutNodeJssdk.orders.OrdersGetRequest(orderID);

  let order;
  try {
    order = payPalClient.execute(request);
  } catch (err) {

    // 4. Handle any errors from the call
    console.error(err);
    return res.send(500);
  }

  // 5. Validate the transaction details are as expected
  if (order.result.purchase_units[0].amount.value !== '220.00') {
    return res.send(400);
  }

    
    
    return res.status(200).json({ message: JSON.stringify(order.result)})
}

export default handler;
```

Im not able to convert it to Next.js Could somebody show me the example for Next.js?

EDIT:

If I console.log my request im getting:

```
OrdersGetRequest {
  path: '/v2/checkout/orders/9JS050507F3815039?',
  verb: 'GET',
  body: null,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}
```

And after that at number 5 there is the error comming:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'purchase_units' of undefined
    at handler (webpack-internal:///./pages/api/hi.js:26:20)
    at apiResolver .. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/Development/nextjs/uploadcloudinary/node_modules/@paypal/paypalhttp/lib/paypalhttp/http_client.js:136:22)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:47190) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work! For everyone who wants a fast and solid `Next.JS` solution on how to check for transaction details by paypal api can use my code:

```
const checkoutNodeJssdk = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk');

const clientId = 'your client id';
const clientSecret = 'your client secret';
const environment = new checkoutNodeJssdk.core.SandboxEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret);
const payPalClient = new checkoutNodeJssdk.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment);


export default async (req, res) => {

    // 1. Get the order ID from the request body
    const orderID = 'orderid';

    // 2. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
    let request = await new checkoutNodeJssdk.orders.OrdersGetRequest(orderID);
    
    let order;
    try {
        order = await payPalClient.execute(request);
    } catch (err) {

        // 3. Handle any errors from the call
        console.error(err);
        return res.send(500);
    }

    // 4. Validate the transaction details are as expected
    // Here you can do your own checks on the order
      if (order.result.purchase_units[0].amount.value !== '220.00') {
        return res.send(400);
      }

    // return whatever you want. If you check the order.result you can see the whole return from paypal
    // with all the fields you also can use in 4. for your own checks
    return res.status(200).json({ message: order.result })
}
```